# Preciso compactar varios arquivos separados com powershell

Tags: powershell, arquivo-zip

Preciso montar um script para compactar arquivos de log um por um, cheguei nessa linha, ele chama o 7zip, lista os arquivos,  mas retorna "The system cannot find the file specified." sendo que a pasta está cheia de arquivos de log.

```
dir C:\Arquivos\Log\*.log | ForEach-Object { & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a $_.BaseName $_.Name }
```

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que você não comprimi os arquivos utilizando a função nativa [Compress-Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7)?

Funciona da mesma forma e não haverá dependência para uma ferramenta externa.

Veja:

```
dir C:\Arquivos\Log\*.log | % { Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $_ -DestinationPath "$_.zip" }
```

Comment: Obrigado Bruno, funcionou do jeito que eu queria. Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

```bat
sl 'C:\Arquivos\Log'; dir *.log | % {& "${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe" a $_.BaseName $_.Name}
```

---

**1.** Entre na pasta onde quer criar os seus arquivos ou ao menos aponte para ela:

```bat
# Entre na pasta: 
Set-Location 'C:\Arquivos\Log' ...

# Ou aponte para ela: 
pushd 'C:\Arquivos\Log'; dir *.log | ... ; popd
```

**2.** Use caminho relativo para o `7zip` ou, defina um caminho para ele:

```bat
# Use caminho relativo:
"${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe"

# Ou defina o caminho dele:
$7z=(Get-Item -r $env:ProgramFiles -Filter 7-Zip\7z.exe -Force -EA 0).fullname
```

**3.** `dir C:\Arquivos\Log\*.log` e `$_.BaseName` resulta na criação dos arquivos na pasta atual de trabalho, onde o PowerShell está ou foi iniciado:

```bat
# Funciona se o usuario atual tem permição de escrita na pasta atual de trabalho

dir C:\Arquivos\Log\*.log | ForEach-Object { & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a $_.BaseName $_.Name }
```

- Algumas edições sugerindo o uso dos itens **1** e **2**:

```bat
Set-Location 'C:\Arquivos\Log'; dir *.log | ForEach-Object {& "${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe" a $_.BaseName $_.Name}

# ou...
sl 'C:\Arquivos\Log'; dir *.log | % {& "${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe" a $_.BaseName $_.Name}
```

```bat
pushd 'C:\Arquivos\Log' ; dir *.log | ForEach-Object {& "${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe" a $_.BaseName $_.Name} ; popd

# ou...
pushd 'C:\Arquivos\Log' ; dir *.log | ? {& "${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe" a $_.BaseName $_.Name} ; popd
```

```bat
$7z=(Get-ChildItem -r $env:ProgramFiles -Filter 7-Zip\7z.exe -Force -EA 0).fullname 
Set-Location 'C:\Arquivos\Log'; ls *.log | ForEach-Object {& "$7z" a $_.BaseName $_.Name} 

# Ou...
$7z=(ls -r $env:ProgramFiles -Filter 7-Zip\7z.exe -Force -EA 0).fullname 
sl 'C:\Arquivos\Log'; ls *.log | ? {& "$7z" a $_.BaseName $_.Name}
```

---

- Algumas leituras adicionais (`/English`):

  [√]  **[Get-Item](https://ss64.com/ps/get-item.html)**

  [√]  **[cd | sl | Set-Location](https://ss64.com/ps/set-location.html)**

  [√]  **[ls | dir | Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-item.html)**

  [√]  **[% | ? | Foreach | ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html)**